# Facebook Graph API limit publishing to fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to publish link to my fan page with 1 request/1 minutes. But today i receive an error when request:

```
Error: It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You’ve been blocked from using it. Learn more about blocks in the Help Center.
```

Now i can not continue pushlish any link.
How much time for unblock my graph api and continue use it again? Pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call will be blocked for 30 minutes and during this time the max score will decay at rate of x points/second where x = n / 3.

You can find a comprehensive description of the Facebook API limits [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting)